# Writing ENV variables to configure an npm module

Tags: node.js, npm

I currently have a project in a loose ES6 module format and my database connection is hard coded. I am wanting to turn this into an npm module and am now facing the issue of how to best allow the end user to configure the code. My first attempt was to rewrite it as classes to be instantiated but it is making the use of the code more convoluted than before so am looking at alternatives.  I am exploring my configuration options. It looks like writing to the process env would be the way but I am pondering potential issues, no-nos and other options I have not considered.

Is having the user write config to process env an acceptable method of configuring an npm module? It's a bit like a global write so am dealing with namespace considerations for one. I have also considered using `package.json` but that's not going to work for things like credentials. Likewise using an rc file is cumbersome. I have not found any docs on the proper methodology if any.

```
process.env['MY_COOL_MODULE_DB'] = ...
```

There are basically 5ish options as I see it:

1. hardcode - not an option
2. create a configured scope such as classes - what I have now and bleh
3. use a config such as node-config - not really a user friendly option for npm
4. store as globals/env. As suggested in comment I can wrap that process in an exported function and thereby ensure that I have a complex non collisive namespace while abstracting that from end user
5. Ask user to create some `.rc` file - I would if I was big time like AWS but not in this case.

I mention this npm use case but this really applies to the general  challenge of configuring code that is exported as functions. I have use cases for classes but when the only need is creating a configured scope at the expense (in my case) of more complex code I am not sure its worth it.

**Update** I realize this is a bit of a discussion question but it's helped me wrap my brain around options. I think something like this:

```
// options.js
let options = {}
export function setOptions(o) { options = o }
export function getOptions(o) { return options }
```

Then have the user call `setOptions()` and call this `getOptions` internally. I realize that since Node requires the module just once that my `options` object will be kept configured as I pass it around.

Comment: To me, it's basically the same as configuring a module by using globals. Why not export a function that will take options, if making a class out of it is too convoluted?

Comment: @robertklep sure but how does this function then store the vars? Its the same challenge. Either 1) hardcode - not an option, 2) create a configured scope such as classes - what I have now and bleh 3) use a config such as node-config - not really a user friendly opton for npm or 4) store as globals/env. So if I pass a function to the user all I end up doing still is making a wrapper around some env. Granted it allows me to create a complicated namespace and abstract that from the user.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand: you're writing a module, that should take particular options (like database credentials), and you're looking for a way to pass those options from application code to your module, is that correct?

Comment: Correct. I am wanting to pull it out of my codebase and npm publish it. I currently use `node-config` or hardcoded exports for personal code but now need an npm friendly solution. I started rewriting the entire thing as classes but I am not thrilled by the end result of using classes in this case. ENV vars work fine but I am exploring potential nonos of this approach (or a big library using only envs themselves I can use as an inspiration)

Comment: @robertklep I am basically not so much looking as to "how" but trying to find solid examples or direction of a similar system

Comment: To be honest, it's an opinion-based question. You can look at your favorite modules in the NPM repository to see how they do it, and pick a method you like.

Comment: I agree and I hesitated posting it but I wanted input of potential issues or ideally some other method I may have overlooked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM modules should IMO be agnostic as to where configuration is *stored*. That should be left up to the developer, and they may pick their favorite method (env vars, rc files, JSON files, whatever).

The configuration can be passed to your module in various ways. A common way is to export a function that takes an options object:

```
export default options => {
  let db = database.connect(options.database);
  ...
}
```

From there, it really depends on what exactly your module provides. If it's just a bunch of loosely coupled functions, you can just return an object:

```
export default options => {
  let db = database.connect(options.database);
  return {
    getUsers() { return db.getUsers() }
  }
}
```

If you want to allow multiple versions of that object to exist simultaneously, you can use classes:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(options) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}

export default options => {
  return new MyClass(options)
}
```

Or export the entire class itself.

If the number of configuration options is limited (say 3 or less), you can also allow them to be passed as separate arguments, instead of passing an object.

Comment: This is the issue of scope that is challenging by exporting things like ES6 modules (as an example). I agree it should be agnostic so I am considering a config function that will then set internal ENV variables

Comment: There is no such thing as an "internal ENV variable", they are global (throughout the process). I don't see how (specifically) ES6 modules make scoping a challenge; don't regular Node modules pose the same problem?

Comment: I mean provide a config function as you suggested then use that to store to an env that is internal in the sense that its abstracted from the user.  Any function really that is not configured/scoped by configuration through instantation

Comment: Im going to close this question and pick this answer as close enough.